# Как исправить - PHP Warning: Division by zero?

Tags: php, smarty

В управлении игровым сервером (SourceBans++ 1.6.3) есть такая ошибка (точнее в журналах поддомена, на котором он находится):

*[Fri May 22 09:29:30.770872 2020] [php7:warn] [pid 10749] [client ip:port] PHP Warning:  Division by zero in /var/www/www-userroot/data/www/bans.mysite.ru/includes/smarty/plugins/function.math.php(94) : eval()'d code on line 1, referer: iphost*

Вот строка, которую он "жалуется":

```
eval("\$smarty_math_result = " . $equation . ";");
```

Вот ссылка полный код
https://pastebin.com/d6WShcc1

Можно это исправить?

Comment: Скорее всего, исправить можно. Но нам для этого мало информации. Нужно знать, чему равно `$equation`. Там скорее всего что-то вроде `100 / 0`. А значит нужно найти место, где формируется эта переменная и обработать этот случай.

Comment: поиск делал через FileSeek по запросу внутри текстовых файлов:
по $equation - это оно?
   `preg_match_all('!(?:0x[a-fA-F0-9]+)|([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)!', $equation, $match);`



Ага, вот наверное оно, по запросу в поиске просто equation
`<div class="progress-bar bg-warning progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-width="{math equation="( n - c ) / ( ( e - c ) / 100 )" e=$ban_times[$index].e c=$ban_times[$index].c n=$smarty.now}">`
Оно?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка внутри функций smarty вызвана неверными входными данными. Вообще применение подобных функций тут весьма избыточно и излишне усложняет код шаблона (вообще не представляю зачем в смарти в принципе такой функцонал).

Расчитайте нужные значения в шаблоне.

```
{$nc = $smarty.now - $ban_times[$index].c}
{$ec = $ban_times[$index].e - $smarty.now}
{$w = $ec ? ($nc/$ec/100) : "какое-то значение"}
<div class="progress-bar bg-warning progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated"
     role="progressbar" aria-width="{$w}" >
```

Вообще не особо похоже, что ошибка в этом шаблоне, поскольку в знаменателе сравнивается `$smarty.now`, то есть текущая метка времени. и вероятность, что она совпадает не велика. так что я бы на вашем мсте избавился бы вообще от всех включений `{math ...}` из шаблонов.

и на случай, если у вас там все это дело выводится в виде

```
{foreach $ban_times as $index => $v}
```

то в формулах можно использовать `{$v.c}, {$v.e}` а не `{$ban_times[$index]}`

Comment: Если честно, вообще не понимаю, что нужно рассчитывать.
Не понимаю просто, что этот плагин считает там. Не могли бы помочь.
Вот шаблон, в котором находится вышеуказанная строка
[PasteBin page_bans.tpl](https://pastebin.com/w2RAydkA)